# Eloquent Very slow when using remote MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I recently had to transfer my database to a remote server.

I used Postman to connect to PHP running on localhost to make the same requests. Here are the results,

> MySQL on Localhost and Eloquent : ~30ms
>
> MySQL on Remote Server and Eloquent : ~2.7 seconds
>
> MySQL on Localhost and PHP: ~10ms
>
> MySQL on Remote Server and PHP: ~850ms

The average ping from my computer to the the remote server ip is about 150ms.

Here is the PHP script I used,

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "select * from `online` where `online`.`id` = 1 limit 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

var_dump($result);
```

For eloquent, I just used `Online::find(1)`.

I still haven't tried running eloquent on a server, but is this normal? Should I steer away from using eloquent if I am going to be using remote mysql databases on different servers?

**EDIT:**

I was changing some values, and when I removed the charset and collation value from eloquent config, the response time improved to 1.7s which is 1s faster.

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

Comment: So obviously eloquent is going to be slower automatically as it does alot of things so you do not have to write out the sql statements and alot of things to pre-format the result set.  Those have performance costs but you gain productivity.   So naturally a cut down optimized sql statement without all the boilerplate code will be much faster.  But take longer to write.  Laravel was to make things easier but not always faster.

Comment: Yes but from 850ms to an average of 2.7s, seems like quite a lot

Comment: Can you share your eloquent code?  Maybe you are doing something that can be optimized.  Are you using just eloquent or all of laravel?

Comment: Just using eloquent. I used `Online::find(1)` for testing. What other codes do you need?

Comment: I have added an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Eloquent** vs **MySQLi Native RAW Execution**

`Eloquent` is slower than `Native MySQLi Execution` because it has a lot of built-in features. But, `Eloquent` will make your code clean and easy. And providing better **security**.

**Localhost** vs **Remote Host**

When we talk about the `Local Server`, The performance depends on your local environment. But, When you use `Remote Host`, The performance will change because of the following reasons.

1. The network connectivity.
2. The location of your remote host.
3. The performance of your remote host.

**Best Practice / Architecture**

When deploy an application to the production, Usually we don't keep database and application in same server. In production, Experts do following things to increase the database performance.

1. Using Database Replication (across zones).
2. Indexing.
3. Using Caches.